# eclipse C++ remote compilation using cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, eclipse-cdt

Till now we are compiling our C++ project in CentOS using cmake files. Everything is working fine, now instead of putty we are looking for an IDE which will do the job from windows.

I tried with eclipse but not getting step by step documents which will do. I tried in eclipse neon and eclipse for C++ development. All works fine for local but when I say build should happen on Centos nothing works.

1. Using ssh remote system explorer able to view all the files.
2. selected the folder in system explorer and "Create remote project".
3. Able to see the project in the project explorer and all my files/folders are present and .project files also present.
4. in the .project file apart from name rest other tags are empty.
5. All the source folder has CMakeList.txt but how to use that in eclipse is question?
6. When I say build on eclipse it should build the src code on Centos.
7. Not sure which version of eclipse and additional tools needs to be installed.
   If anyone have done already do let me know the execution steps.

Thanks
Vj

Comment: I would install cygwin with an ssh client, mount the directory via `sshfs`, then in `eclipse` do a `makefile` project and add build command as `ssh the_remote_centos make`.

Comment: https://help.eclipse.org/2020-12/index.jsp this looks like current documentation.

Comment: I dont want to install cygwin, looking for some other options. Which version of eclipse I need to install? currently I tried in neon but there I'm not able to see c++ project itself.